# Como guardar los datos de un useDispatch en un useState para después utilizarlos en un form controlado React

Tags: reactjs, redux, usestate

Mi codigo es este:

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const artist = useSelector((state) => state.artistId);

  const title = isEdit === "true" ? "Edit Artist" : "New Artist";
  let name = isEdit === "true" ? artist.name : "";
  const photo = isEdit === "true" ? artist.photo : img;
  let email = isEdit === "true" ? artist.email : "";
  let location = isEdit === "true" ? artist.location : "";
  let biography = isEdit === "true" ? artist.biography : "";

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    location: "",
    biography: "",
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Modal.setAppElement("body");
    if (isEdit === "true") {
      dispatch(getArtistById(idArtist));
    }
  }, [dispatch, isEdit]);
```

el dispatch me trae la informacion de un artista en especifico(pasado por id) y lo obtengo por useSelector(**Estoy utilizando Redux**), todo va bien me trae la información del artista,
pero esa información la quiero guardar en el useState, lo hice de esta manera:

ya que estas variables (name,email,location,biography) vienen de la condicion

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    location: location,
    biography: biography,
  });
```

Pero no me guarda los datos en el useState
Alguien sabe como podría cargar esa información en un useState?

Comment: No esta claro lo que hay en `artist` (lo que trae useSelector) ¿Es un array de objetos o es `artistid`?

Comment: es un objeto,  y me lo trae existosamente, el problema viene cuando intento pasar esos datos al useState, el useState no se me actualiza con los datos pasados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar otro `useEffect`:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    setData({name:artist.name,
    email:artist.email,
    location:artist.location,
    biography:artist.biography})
},[]);
```

Ahora, de acuerdo a la lógica propuesta, el array de dependencias puede configurarse para correr cuando cambie el `artistId`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const artist = useSelector((state) => state.artistId);

React.useEffect(()=>{
    setData({name:artist.name,
    email:artist.email,
    location:artist.location,
    biography:artist.biography})
},[artist.artistId, artist]);
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste mucho, me solucionaste la duda, aplique lo que me sugeriste y hice una inicialización, y me sirvió